# how to save an visualisation as a png

Tags: r, png, cairo

Please advise how to save an image in png using a script and set a max extension

```
  chord_data <- data %>%
  select(from, to = to, value = value) %>%
  as.data.frame()

tmp <- chordDiagram(chord_data, annotationTrack = "grid", 
                preAllocateTracks = list(track.height = max(strwidth(unlist(dimnames(chord_data))))))

circos.track(track.index = 1, 
               panel.fun = function(x, y) {
               circos.text(CELL_META$xcenter, 
                        CELL_META$ylim[1], 
                        CELL_META$sector.index, 
                        facing = "clockwise", 
                        niceFacing = TRUE, 
                        adj = c(0, 0.6), cex = 0.8)
            }, bg.border = NA) # here set bg.border to NA is important
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
png("my_png_file.png")

chord_data <- data %>%
  select(from, to = to, value = value) %>%
  as.data.frame()

tmp <- chordDiagram(chord_data, annotationTrack = "grid", 
                preAllocateTracks = list(track.height = max(strwidth(unlist(dimnames(chord_data))))))

circos.track(track.index = 1, 
               panel.fun = function(x, y) {
               circos.text(CELL_META$xcenter, 
                        CELL_META$ylim[1], 
                        CELL_META$sector.index, 
                        facing = "clockwise", 
                        niceFacing = TRUE, 
                        adj = c(0, 0.6), cex = 0.8)
            }, bg.border = NA) # here set bg.border to NA is important

dev.off()
```